# Mysqli UPDATE SET WHERE syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So I had this chunk of php code

```
if($_POST['action']=='newComment')
{
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "nested_comment");
    $new_post = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['content']);
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT @myLeft := lft FROM comment
                            WHERE lft = '1';
                            UPDATE comment SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE rgt > @myLeft;
                            UPDATE comment SET lft = lft + 2 WHERE lft >= @myLeft;
                            INSERT INTO comment(content, lft, rgt) VALUES('$new_post', @myLeft, @myLeft + 1);");

    if($result)
        echo "ok";
    else
        echo $mysqli->error;

}
```

When I run this, an error is thrown:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE comment SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE rgt > @myLeft;
>                                   UPDATE comment SET' at line 3

But when I put the sql query into Sequel Pro(Mac), it works well. I tried many of other posts' solution and none of them work. Is there something wrong with my syntax, or something wrong with mysql version? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Avoid using MySQL variables unless its part of a procedure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you are trying to execute multiple statements in one go

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php

Mysqli has a function for that

`mysqli_multi_query()`

Please note that any SQL injections found can now be chained together. Be careful when using it

> Security considerations
>
> The API functions mysqli_query() and mysqli_real_query() do not set a
>   connection flag necessary for activating multi queries in the server.
>   An extra API call is used for multiple statements to reduce the
>   likeliness of accidental SQL injection attacks. An attacker may try to
>   add statements such as ; DROP DATABASE mysql or ; SELECT SLEEP(999).
>   If the attacker succeeds in adding SQL to the statement string but
>   mysqli_multi_query is not used, the server will not execute the
>   second, injected and malicious SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So if I use real_escape_string to prevent injection, will this be enough?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string  prefer parametrised query's if possible